Sum of random variables in Sympy
I want to evalute the expectation value and variance of sums over random variables with sympy.
Let's say x is Poisson distributed with some lambda > 0. I have a sum over n samples from x_i. My final term y is then the square of the sum:
y = (sum_{i=0}^{n-1} (x_i)^2) ^2
This should yield E(y) = n * E(x_i ^ 4) + n * (n-1) E(x_i^2)^2.
The higher moments of a poisson distribution can be looked up.
I'd like to verify that with sympy, but already
import sympy as sy
from sympy.stats import Poisson, E
n,i = sy.Var("n i", integer=True)
mu = sy.Var("mu", positive=True)
y = sy.Sum(Poisson("x_i", mu)**2,(i,0,n-1))**2
y.simplify()

just yields n^2 * x_i^4.
It seems that sympy does treat x_i as n independent variables, but only as one variable.
Is there something I can do to achieve what I want?

To clarify, there has been an answer which was deleted. The mentioned answer didn't catch my problem entirely - it boils down to whether it is possible to create an array of random variables with symbolic length in sympy.

I don't think you can create arrays of discrete random variables in sympy like this (but I'd be delighted if somebody else could show it). There is a hint in the sympy documentation that you might be able to do it for normally-distributed random variables (and a few others), but not Poisson.
I think the best that you can do is use sympy to find the higher moments of a single variable for any given distribution and then combine them in a way similar to the following (based on your example):

where each variable shares the distribution of X and the last term relies on X_i and X_j being independent when i is not equal to j.
For example,
import sympy as sp
from sympy.stats import Poisson, E

n, mu = sp.symbols( "n mu")
m2, m4 = sp.symbols("m2 m4")

m2 = E( Poisson( "x", mu ) ** 2 )      # 2nd moment (of a single variable)
m4 = E( Poisson( "x", mu ) ** 4 )      # 4th moment (of a single variable)
y = n * m4 + ( n ** 2 - n ) * m2 ** 2
y = y.simplify().expand()
y = sp.collect( y, n )
print( y )

Output:
n**2*(mu**4 + 2*mu**3 + mu**2) + n*(4*mu**3 + 6*mu**2 + mu)


Thanks man! I've also chosen that path now. It becomes quite tedious (because the term I want to calculate is a bit longer...), but sympy still helps preventing unnecessary mistakes. I've tried looking into randomindexedsymbol (listed in here: https://github.com/sympy/sympy/blob/master/sympy/stats/rv.py), but wasn't able to make it work and it isn't documented very well either.

Also, how were you able to use latex inside your answer? Wasn't able to use it for my question...

It's not LaTeX, @WhyNoPython. It's an image (and it was actually screenshot from Word!) You need enough "reputation" on this site to incorporate it directly in an answer or a question, rather than as a link to an image-serving site. There are a number of recent questions on this site regarding features of Sympy stats, including yours, that the developers of Sympy might consider for future integration in the software. It is possible that Maple or Mathematica might be able to help you, but I'm no expert on them.
